# Merging overlapping duplicate geometry

Tags: mesh

I have a simple plane, to which I applied the 'cell fracture' add-on. The add-on created separate layers for each fracture, so I selected everything and used 'ctrl+j' to join all of the layers into one mesh and removed the faces:

[image]

Now I would like to have this mesh solid and 'connected' as I see it visually, but when I zoom in, I see that the edges are not connected, but are overlapping:

[image]

I tried 'remove doubles', but it 'simplified' the mesh and altered its pattern:

[image]

The closest I could get it to remove the extra vertices was using the 'Limited Dissolve', which removed all the extra vertices:

[image]

but still the original problem persists and the vertices/edges are still overlapping:

[image]

How can I 'merge' these edges so that I could get a solid mesh? Thank you!

Comment: It appears you had the threshold too high when you removed doubles.

Comment: By joining and merging the vertices you are going back to one solid object, which is mostly undoing the results of the cell fracture.